# How to do drag and drop on subviews on NSScrollView ? Exactly same as LaunchPad

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsscrollview

I have searched a lot. But confused, so i come here to solve my query.

I want to make view which is exactly same as LaunchPad of mac os. having expertise on iOS programming not on mac.

This is my beginner time to mac osx programming.

Please advice which components are best part of it.

I have started with NSScrollView and inside subviews are inherits of NSView.

But i have few confusion on it.

**Does drag operation accept by subviews of NSScrollView ??** (Usually in iOS there are some tricky logic to achieve this).

**Is this right part to use while Drag and Drop or else ??** [Drag and Drop Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000069-SW1)

There are some mouse event are also. I suppose this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventObjectsTypes/EventObjectsTypes.html) would be helpful.

Please suggest few links or blogs which push me to ahead in this task.

please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your view or window needs to register to receive drags for the pasteboard types you are interested in:

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:@[(id)kUTTypeURL]];
```

You will get a first callback when dragging enters the view:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info
{
    NSPasteboard    *draggingPasteboard = [info draggingPasteboard];
    //  NSDragOperation draggingSourceOperationMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];

    NSArray         *classes            = @[[NSURL class]];
    NSDictionary    *options            = @{NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey : @YES};

    if ([draggingPasteboard canReadObjectForClasses:classes options:options]) {
        //      NSArray *fileURLs = [draggingPasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes
        //                                                            options:options];
        //
        //      if ([fileURLs count] != 1) {
        //          return NSDragOperationNone;
        //      }

        return NSDragOperationLink;
    }

    return NSDragOperationNone;
}
```

If dragging ends on your view (e.g. the file is dropped), you will get another callback where you can read from the pasteboard and process the item you received:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info
{
    NSPasteboard *draggingPasteboard = [info draggingPasteboard];

    if ([draggingPasteboard canReadObjectForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]] options:nil]) {
        return [self addItemWithDragInfo:info];
    }

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) addItemWithDragInfo:info:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info
{
    NSPasteboard    *draggingPasteboard = [info draggingPasteboard];

    NSArray         *classes            = @[[NSURL class]];
    NSDictionary    *options            = @{NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey : @YES};

    NSArray         *fileURLs           = [draggingPasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];

    // TODO: Do something with those files…

    return YES;
}
```

BTW, LaunchPad probably uses NSCollectionView or IKImageBrowserView. These views already include some support for drag and drop.

Comment: Are you sure that NSCollectionView will be helpful in my case ?

Comment: I use IKImageBrowserView in my Mac applications (HoudahSpot, HoudahGeo and Tembo – http://www.hoduah.com ). I remember repeatedly evaluating NSCollectionView. Unfortunately I keep forgetting why each time I end up preferring IKImageBrowserView over NSCollectionView.

Comment: Is there any options available to make Groping in ?? As like folder of Utilities in LaunchPad.

Comment: I don't think so. You might be able to implement that by temporarily displaying a second browser view above the main one.

Comment: I m too much confused. I have just did one drag and drop feature with IKImageBrowserView. But i am not sure that will it be do same as LaunchPad view. Please suggest me how to move ahead on right track.

Comment: By "your view", do you mean the NSScrollView? I've subclassed NSScrollView and implemented draggingEntered etc for my subclass and I call registerForDraggedTypes on awakeFromNib but the dragging methods never get called... :(